# asp.net html,body{height:100%} not working

Tags: html, asp.net

I wanted to create a div that will have a 100 percent height. but it's not working. I also tried to search for a solution here on stackoverflow but unfortunately, none of them worked. I thought that by placing 100 percent on both html and body will make it work but it didn't. here is my markup then followed by my css. I'm using asp.net vs2010. I'm new to designing a web page.

```
   <div class="hundredpercentdiv">
   <p>This content should have 100% height</p>
   </div>

   html,body{
   height:100%;
   }

   body{
   background:#fff;
   color:#333;
   }

   p{
   font-size:2em;
   text-align:center;
   }

   .hundredpercentdiv{
   height:100%;
   background-color:Green;
   }
```

Comment: Show us what you have yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default styling of `body` and `p` tag i.e. their default `margin` to `0px`,

```css
html,body{
   height:100%;
   }

   body{
   background:#fff;
   color:#333;
   margin:0; /*Add this*/
   }

   p{
   font-size:2em;
   text-align:center;
   margin:0; /*Add this*/
   }

   .hundredpercentdiv{
   height:100%;
   background-color:Green;
   }
```

```html
<div class="hundredpercentdiv">
  <p>This content should takes up 100% of the viewport</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a solution. I'll make sure to try it and get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome. Mostly all tags have some default styling and that is the reason you are getting white space in your page. So make changes as above.

Comment: I don't get it why it's working on jsfiddle.net and notepad++ but not working on asp.net.

Comment: No idea. But this fill 100% viewport height. Once removing the margin.

Comment: Are there possible alternative ways to get the 100 percent height? I am truly sorry.

Comment: I'll mark your answer above as acceptable as an appreciation. I'm reading vh unit and it actually did the work, however, I read some articles and some are pointing out that it doesn't work properly on safari and some browsers. Thank you so much